# How do I find the exact compiler executable Visual Studio is calling?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio with C++.

For a particular reason, I now need to use CMake to build a piece of the project. I would like to tell CMake to use the same compiler I normally use with Visual Studio.

How can I find the exact `cl.exe` compiler executable path used by Visual Studio? There are a few of these on my machine.

Comment: Why would you tell CMake that? CMake understands Visual Studio, and can generate MSBuild projects (The build system used behind the scenes by Visual Studio). Visual Studio itself has no idea where cl.exe is either.

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, bump up the build output verbosity to Detailed.  You'll now see it executing cl.exe in the Output window.

Comment: XY Problem. Use CMake's Visual Studio generator and it will find everything. cl.exe by itself is NOT enough and will not work without a whole bunch of environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Inside VS in menu Tools > Command Line select *Developer Command Prompt* then run `where cl`. You can also select *Developer PowerShell* and run `Get-Command cl` or specifically `(Get-Command cl).Source`

[image: Example developer powershell]

You can also open start menu, type **developer** and open the desired terminal

Comment: How is it that `where cl` does not work, but  `where.exe cl` works?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 in powershell `where` is an alias for `Where-Object` so you must use `where.exe` to call the executable. In cmd you just need `where`

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version, it probably lies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx86\x86` (for 32-bit). `14.26.28801` will be different in your PC though